# Execute tasks with the same name in multi module project one after another

Tags: gradle

I have a project that consists of 5 projects. All of these projects have a `publishToMavenLocal` task. I used to call them all together like this:

```
task publishAll( dependsOn: [:project1:publishToMavenLocal, :project2:publishToMavenLocal, :project3:publishToMavenLocal....])
```

But now `project2` depends on `project1` and `project5` depends on `project1, project2 and project3`.

how can I do something like

```
tasks.register('publishAll') {
    dependsOn project1.tasks.publishToMavenLocal
    dependsOn project2.tasks.publishToMavenLocal
    dependsOn project3.tasks.publishToMavenLocal
    ....

    project2.tasks.publishToMavenLocal.dependsOn project1.tasks.publishToMavenLocal
    project5.tasks.publishToMavenLocal dependsOn [project2.tasks.publishToMavenLocal, project3.tasks.publishToMavenLocal, project4.tasks.publishToMavenLocal]
}
```

I tried this, but it always return null.

```
    dependsOn project(':project1').tasks.findByPath('publishToMavenLocal')
    dependsOn project(':project1').tasks.findByName('publishToMavenLocal')
```